# Creating default object from empty value i Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I have some trouble in my projects in Laravel 5.7 . Can you help me? please..

[Creating default object from empty value (Click here to see screenshoot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaN7V.png)

This my Update Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $update = jadwal::where('slug', $slug) -> first();
    $update->judul = $request->judul;
    $update->studio = $request->studio;
    $update->waktu = $request->tanggal ." | Pukul " .$request->waktu ." WIB";

    $update->update();
    return redirect() -> route('jadwal.index');
}
```

And then this my update form

```
<form  method="post" action="{{route('jadwal.update', $edit->slug)}}}" class="t-margin-top-1 t-padding t-margin-right-1">
            @csrf

            {{method_field('PUT')}}

                    <input value="{{$edit->judul}}" type="text" name="judul" class="t-input" placeholder="Masukan Judul Film">

                   <input value="{{$edit->studio}}" type="text" name="studio" class="t-input" placeholder="Masukan Nama Studionya">

                   <input value="{{$edit->tanggal}}" type="date" class="t-input" name="tanggal" title="Masukan Tanggal Pemutaran">

                   <input type="time" value="{{$edit->waktu}}" name="waktu" class="t-input" title="Masukan Waktu Pemutaran">

                   <div class="t-margin-top-1">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="t-input-submit" value="Perbarui Jadwal">    
                    <input type="reset" class="t-input-reset" name="reset" value="Reset Data">
                   </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: The error happened because the $update variable is NULL

Comment: but in screenshoot files, on $data->judul = $request->judul; are highlighted. So in $request -> judul are failed to request. How to solved bro?

Comment: Do `dd($request);` in your `update` function and post the output.

Comment: I can't Understand? How to do Do dd($request); in my update ?

Comment: No, the problem is not at the $request->judul, but at $update->judul. Because $update variable is NULL. So what happened is you try to do this NULL->judul, and you can't do that.

Comment: In that case, replace this line `$update = jadwal::where('slug', $slug) -> first();` with this `$update = jadwal::where('slug', $slug) -> firstOrFail();` in `update` function.

Comment: it show 404 Message bro

Comment: That must be because you don't have any matching record for that particular slug. Now try and find what `$slug` value are you passing to `update`.

Comment: Okay that's works Thanks All, slug is varchar and then I try change slug to id (id is Integer with Auto Increment) and finally I successfully solved this problem. How it works??

Comment: I don't think you have solved your problem. You wanted the record to be matching with a slug. Why are you now giving id? You should actually find for which value of `slug` are you getting the error. Because, you don't have that record in your DB

Comment: just use firstOrFail method instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
jadwal::updateOrCreate([
    'judul' => $request->judul;
    'studio' => $request->studio;
    'waktu' => $request->tanggal ." | Pukul " .$request->waktu ." WIB",
    'slug' => $slug 
]);
```

But be careful, if slug isn't unique you might change more than one entry